# Are low amounts of caffeine, e.g. Coke, bad for IBS? If so, advice on how IBS sufferers can get a burst of energy?

Tags: caffeine, irritable-bowel-syndrome, fibromyalgia, chronic-fatigue-synd.-cfs, energy

I unfortunately, am one of the many that suffer from IBS (irritable bowel syndrome). I also have the luck of suffering from fibromyalgia (so I have chronic fatigue), but I have a very demanding job and life so sometimes I a get a little help from my friend, aka Coca Cola. However, I heard rumors that caffeine consumption can irritate the bowels and make IBS symptoms all the more worse. AH! I think I have noticed this personally. (But wasn't sure if it's all in my head because I heard the rumor). Any way, what is a person with low-energy and IBS suppose to do?

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1z4iyq_e07-the-power-of-the-placebo_tv

Comment: Stimulants such as caffeine, alcohol, hot food, cigarettes, etc. are all bad for people with IBS. No, it's not just a rumor. It stimulates your intestine in a bad way. As to an alternative to Coke, some traditional Chinese medicine might work. As you probably already know, most drinks for boosting your energy has caffeine in them which you might wanna stay away from.

Comment: I found some alternatives on this page: http://www.newhealthadvisor.com/alternatives-to-caffeine.html